# how to use Asynchronous delegates on a void return method

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

i want to make a method async

```
public static void PrepareData<T>()
{
 // prepare data ....
}
```

i was trying to do the following

```
Func method = PrepareData<T>;
method.invoke
...
```

but it complain Func must specify something e,g Func

so my question is, how to make a void return method asyn??

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) instead of `Func`. The `Action` family is for functions with a `void` return type, `Func` is for those that actually return something.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `Action<T>` instead